# Error when creating a vue project with CLI

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to create a Vue project using the Vue CLI in Ubuntu, but keep getting the same error. I've already installed the Vue CLI using `sudo npm i -g @vue/cli`.

Here is the error message:

> 00h00m00s 0/0: :  ERROR  Error: Command failed: yarn config get registry
>   ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config'
>
> Error: Command failed: yarn config get registry
>
> ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config'
>
> at makeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
>       at Promise.all.then.arr (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3994

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the `error` it's trying to find yarn's config file in `node_modules`. You does not have `yarn` packageManager installed in your system I believe

Try this
`vue config -s packageManager npm`

and re-run `vue create`

Answer (score 4):

a) uninstall yarn so create will fall back to npm

b) explictly tell it to use npm:

```
vue create myproject --packageManager npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling node and npm then restarting my pc and then reinstalling them worked for me.

`sudo apt remove nodejs`

`sudo apt autoremove`

Reinstalling it

`sudo apt install nodejs`

`sudo apt install npm`

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me.
Even though yarn was already installed, I ran

```
npm install -g yarn
```

And repeated

```
vue create project-name
```